# Is there a way to avoid using a counter in nested for statement?

Tags: python

```
index = 0
for i in range(16):
    if flags >> i & 1:
        decoded_matrix[0][i] = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.dtype(np.float32).newbyteorder(">"))[index]
            index += 1
```

Is there a way to avoid the "index" variable? It increments every time flags >> i & 1 for numbers 1 - 16.

Comment: probably because of the flags condition

Comment: what's the & 1 for?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid index